# Run 'TERM=ansi' when shell starts

Tags: shell, term

I use `shell` inside emacs but by default it prints output in 1 color.

However, when I use `grep`, I would like to see substring I'm searching highlighted.

To see colors, I can manually type `TERM=ansi` when shell starts, but I wonder if there is a way to run shell with `TERM` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are using bash?  If you add `TERM=ansi` to your `.bashrc` all interactive non-login shells that are opened will have it set (including emacs).

Otherwise if You only want that set in emacs you can create a file `~/.emacd.d/init_bash.sh` (replacing "bash" with your default shell if not bash) containing `TERM=ansi`.

From the `shell` docstring (`C-h f shell`):

> If a file ‘~/.emacs_SHELLNAME’ exists, or
>   ‘~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh’, it is given as initial input...

Comment: Thanks! Adding `init_bash.sh` works!